# Почему может не работать?

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь и понимание.

Начал изучать Vue-js и решил сделать велосипед.

Версия vue-js 2.4.2

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<script>
    Vue.component('message',{
        template: '<input v-model="message" @keyup.enter="saveMessage">',
        data: function () {
            return{
                message: '';
            }
        },
        methods: {
            saveMessage: function () {
                console.log(this.message);
            }
        }
    });

    new Vue({
        el: 'body'
    })
</script>
```

```html
<div>
    <message></message>
</div>
```

Хочу, чтобы на странице выводилась форма в которой можно писать текст, нажимая enter этот текст записывался в консоль (для проверки сделал,работает ли).

Но на странице ничего не появляется. В чем может быть проблема, что не так?

Заранее спасибо за ответ. )

Comment: `message: '' ;` Что это за `;`?

Comment: Честно. Не знаю, видно на автомате поставил. Но если его убрать, то все равно не выходит запустить.

Comment: + Вместо `el: 'body'` сделай `el: 'div'` Со второй версии вроде нельзя ни к  `body` ни к `html` привязываться.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich Во. Спасибо большое. ) 
Заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо опечатки, (которую приметил @Duoxx), а именно, наличие `;` в возвращаемом объекте, со второй версии [не рекомендуется](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.3) привязываться к `body` или `html`. О чём кстати в консоли `vue` должен предупреждать.

Требуется заменить `el: 'body'` например на `el: 'div'`. А лучше задать `id` и привязываться к нему:

```
<div id="app">
    <message></message>
</div>
```

и соответственно:

```
...
new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    })
```

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо. С: